# creating a new square image from a rectangular image without cropping

Tags: php, image, gd

I want to allow users to upload an image file and then I want to process it so that it ends up as a square, except without cropping it. So say someone uploads an image 1400wide and 800px tall, I want to turn that into an image 1400x1400, with the uploaded image centered between two white bars, top and bottom, to make up the extra height.

How do I do this? All solutions I've found so far involve cropping, or are in a different language.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need to center a resized thumbnail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220840/need-to-center-a-resized-thumbnail)

Comment: This is a very common and well solved problem in PHP. There are many duplicates across Stack Overflow.

Comment: Please [don't add signatures or taglines to your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you would need to do:

1. Load the images and data.
2. Get the image data (`MIME`, `height`, `width`) and take the max of height and width to determine the overall dimension.
3. Create an image identifier using `imagecreatetruecolor` with the max value attained in Step 2.
4. Use some simple math to paste the image in the right position (using left and right distances of: `(MAX_VALUE - MIN_VALUE) / 2`, where `MAX_VALUE` would be 1400px and `MIN_VALUE` would be 800px in your example)
5. Save the image identifier using GD functions.

**Reference**: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php